# Integrate UIView and GLKView inside of UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, glkit

I use Xcode 4.3.2 with iOS SDK 5.1.

I want to create a view controller in my storyboard, which contains a GLKView on the half screen and Buttons + Text on the other half.

I tried the put both in a UIViewController but could get it to work.

Any ideas? Articles? Tutorials?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a instance of GLKViewController in UIViewController and now add the GLKViewController as a child view controller and also add GLKView as a subview to the UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would follow is:

1. create your `GLKView`/`GLKViewController` as usual;
2. add you `UIView` containing buttons and text as a subview to the `GLKView`.

I would do the second step programmatically, in `GLKViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: that's not really what i need, cause the subview will cover my opengl scene. but the scene just should be half the screen. idea?